# Extracting Assembly line code from an executable in Ghidra

Tags: assembly, ghidra

I'm using Ghidra to reverse engineer an EXE file and save its assembly line code only. Does Ghidra have any function or scripts which exports the assembly line code? I don't want to manually copy the code from the Listing window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you ask about one line or the whole program.

One assembly line can be obtain for example by such script:

```
addr = toAddr(<address>)
print(currentProgram.getListing().getInstructionAt(addr))
```

if we are talking about the whole program

```
for instr in currentProgram.getListing().getInstructions(True):
    print(instr)
```

but I guess the last one can take a while. More information can be found in the docs about [Listing](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/model/listing/Listing.html) object.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted.

The program has to be analyzed for this to work, I wrote a script which analyzes the program and then extracts the assembly code, but the issue is that the first time i run the script, it can't detect the current Listing window and gets a NoneType error (even though the script was analyzed), but if I run the script again after it has been analyzed once, then the assembly code is displayed. 

Is there a way where the script extracts the assembly code the first time the script has been run?

Comment: share a link to this script. I'll have a look

Comment: I fixed it, thank you for your time!