# Extract disassembly from Ghidra for reassembling

Tags: disassembly, ghidra, motorola

How can I extract a code listing from a Ghidra project such that I can reassemble with something like vasm? I have gone through a memory snapshot and disassembled the code and marked data sections etc. to a point where I would like to check my work.

Further to the question and answer in [Extracting Assembly line code from an executable in Ghidra](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25261/extracting-assembly-line-code-from-an-executable-in-ghidra) I would like to extract line labels, plate comments and EOL comments.

Here is an example:

[image: example Ghidra screenshot]

Here's what I'd like the extracted code to look like:

```
; Extracted data blocks
STATUS_STRING_BUFFER:
        dc.b 0
        dc.b 0
        dc.b 0
        dc.b 0
; etc
CURRENT_STATUS_MESSAGE_CODE:
        dc.b 0

; Extracted subroutine
**************************************************************
* Display a message in the status bar                        *
**************************************************************
DisplayStatusMessage:
        movem.l {a2, a1, d5},-(sp)
        lea STATUS_STRING_BUFFER, a1
        clr.w d0
        move.b (a0)+,d0
        move.b d0,CURRENT_STATUS_MESSAGE_CODE    ; Store Message byte
        andi.b #$7f                              ; Mask out msb
        ; ... etc
```

As you can see there are a number of things to do including:

1. Extract data blocks
2. Convert `db`, `dw`, `ddw` to `dc.b`, `dc.w`, `dc.l`
3. Convert hex from `0xNN` to `$NN` notation
4. Extract plate comments
5. Extract labels
6. Extract disassembled code lines
7. Extract EOL comments

Is there a readily available script for this or can someone show a working example?

Comment: Have you looked at the "Export Program" menu dialog? None of the options in that dialog do exactly what you are looking for, but the C/C++ export and the ASCII export could be combined by some other script to produce what you are looking for.

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook Yes, this could be a starting point. I may have to run a script outside of Ghidra to do what I want.